# How to use a variable during class initialization in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, python-module

I have 3 python scripts say `script1.py` `script2.py` `script3.py`
I have imported `script2` and `script3` classes in script1.

When I execute, I run only the `script1` and It will call the functions in `script2` as needed.

but in `script2.py` I have a Class, inside class I have a variable `y_path` and this is set to a `string` concatenated with another string variable, something like shown below

```
class LAUtils(BBCAPIInfra):

     y_path = "/foo/bar/abc/__dname__/pfile.yml".replace("__dname__",str(dname))
```

The value of `dname` is got using a method in `script1`

here is a snippet from `script1`  getting dname

```
from foo.bar.script2 import LAUtils
class CommonSetup
    def some_method(self, local_parameter):
      dname = call_a_method(local_parameter)
```

My question is how can I update the value of variable `dname` during class initialization in `script2`, for example, if the `dname` value is `MCSX` , I want the variable `y_path` to set it to `/foo/bar/abc/MCSX/pfile.yml` already during class initialization.

Comment: Why not using the `__init__`method ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an constructor

```
class LAUtils(BBCAPIInfra):
    def __init__(dname)
        self.y_path = "/foo/bar/abc/__dname__/pfile.yml".replace("__dname__",str(dname))
```

now you will be able to use it this way:

```
la_utils = LAUtils(dname) 
print(la_utils.ypath)
```

Comment: okay, I will use `__init__` in script2, but how will I pass the variable `dname` from script1 after getting it ?

Comment: can you share the contents of script1? parameters can only be passed in methods like the constructor method i shared earlier

Comment: updated post to add `script1`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use a variable during class initialization (i.e., in the constructor) by defining it as a parameter in the **init** method. When you create an instance of the class, you can pass a value for that parameter, and it will be used during the initialization process.

**Here's a simple example of how to use a variable during class initialization:**

```
class MyClass:
def __init__(self, my_variable):
    self.my_variable = my_variable

def some_method(self):
    print("Value of my_variable:", self.my_variable)
    # Create an instance of the class and pass a value for my_variable
        instance = MyClass("Hello, World!")

    # Call the method that uses the initialized variable
        instance.some_method()
```

**Output:**

```
Value of my_variable: Hello, World!
```

In the above example, the ****init** method** takes a parameter **my_variable**, and the value passed during the instance creation **(MyClass("Hello, World!"))** is assigned to the class attribute **self.my_variable**. Later, we call the **some_method** to access and print the value of **self.my_variable**.

You can use multiple variables in the ****init** method** to initialize different attributes of the class as needed. Each time you create a new instance of the class, you can pass different values for those variables to customize the behavior of each instance.